# Can't make my method concantenate 2 values

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to make the `additional_terms` value include the value for `term_clause`, when `is_term_clause` has a value of `true`.

Is there a way of doing this is a method call, or no? Does it have to be computed?

```
<template>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 align-self-start">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Additional Terms</label>
        <p-check
          class="p-svg p-curve m-2"
          color="success"
          v-model="document.is_term_clause"
          value="1"
          v-on:click="terms"
        >
          <label>Renewal Terms</label>
          <svg slot="extra" class="svg svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
            <path
              d="M7.629,14.566c0.125,0.125,0.291,0.188,0.456,0.188c0.164,0,0.329-0.062,0.456-0.188l8.219-8.221c0.252-0.252,0.252-0.659,0-0.911c-0.252-0.252-0.659-0.252-0.911,0l-7.764,7.763L4.152,9.267c-0.252-0.251-0.66-0.251-0.911,0c-0.252,0.252-0.252,0.66,0,0.911L7.629,14.566z"
              style="stroke: white;fill:white"
            />
          </svg>
        </p-check>
        <textarea-autosize class="form-control" :rows="4" v-model="document.additional_terms"></textarea-autosize>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      now: new Date().toISOString(),
      document: {
        is_term_clause: true,
        term_clause: '',
        additional_terms: '',
      },
    }
  },
  created() {
    if (this.listing != null) {
      this.document.additional_terms =
        'This Contract to Lease is contingent upon Tenants attorney approval within 3 calendar days of its effective date. Should the Tenants attorney not approve the Contract to Lease in his sole and absolute discretion, this Contract to Lease is void as if never binding.'
      this.document.term_clause =
        'Landlord agrees to pay renewal commission in the amount of 5% to listing broker and 5% to co-op broker as compensation for renegotiating lease renewal at end of lease term.'
    }
  },

  methods: {
    terms(evt) {
      if (this.document.is_term_clause == true) {
        this.$emit(
          (this.document.additional_terms =
            this.document.additional_terms + ' ' + this.document.term_clause),
          evt,
        )
      } else {
        this.$emit(
          (this.document.additional_terms = this.document.additional_terms),
          evt,
        )
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should watch for `is_term_clause` changes, and when it's true change `additional_terms` to contain `term_clause`. I think using `watch` is more reliable approach, then tracking changes directly in method.

```js
export default {
  ...
  watch: {
    is_term_clause(val) {
      if (val === true) this.additional_terms = this.term_clause
    },
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: I like this approach. Using watch is better than changing based on a click listener.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're emitting the value in the method, but you don't need to do that to update a variable in the same component.

```
terms() {
    if (this.document.is_term_clause == true) {
        this.document.additional_terms = this.document.additional_terms + ' ' + 
    this.document.term_clause
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but how do I manipulate it to add or delete the term_clause? And if not in method, than where?

Comment: You can do it in the method, as I specified in the code above. You don't need to use this.$emit unless you're trying to send event/data to a parent element.

Comment: Thank you Cathy Ha, that was out me on the right path.